# Removing matching pairs in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For `df`:

```
    id          Date        ITEM_ID TYPE    GROUP
0   13710750    2019-07-01  SLM607  O       X
1   13710760    2019-07-01  SLM607  O       M
2   13710770    2019-07-03  SLM607  O       I
3   13710780    2019-09-03  SLM607  O       N
4   13667449    2019-08-02  887643  O       I
5   13667450    2019-08-02  792184  O       I
6   13728171    2019-09-17  SLM607  I       I
7   13667452    2019-08-02  794580  O       I
```

reproducible example:

```
data = {'id': [13710750, 13710760, 13710770, 13710780, 13667449, 13667450, 13728171, 13667452],
        'Date': ['2019-07-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-03', '2019-09-03', '2019-08-02', '2019-08-02', '2019-09-17', '2019-08-02'],
        'ITEM_ID': ['SLM607', 'SLM607', 'SLM607', 'SLM607', '887643', '792184', 'SLM607', '794580'],
        'TYPE': ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'I', 'O'],
        'GROUP': ['X', 'M', 'I','N','I','I','I', 'I']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

how can I delete pairs of rows that have same values for `ITEM_ID` and `GROUP`, but one with `O` for `TYPE` that comes first, and another one with `I` for `TYPE` that happens later?

Expected outcome:

```
    id          Date        ITEM_ID TYPE    GROUP
0   13710750    2019-07-01  SLM607  O       X
1   13710760    2019-07-01  SLM607  O       M

3   13710780    2019-09-03  SLM607  O       N
4   13667449    2019-08-02  887643  O       I
5   13667450    2019-08-02  792184  O       I

7   13667452    2019-08-02  794580  O       I
```

Comment: What happens if an `O` is matched with multiple ensuing `I`? Many `O` matched by many `I`?

Comment: Hi @BlownhitherMa then take the next immediate 'I' and remove the pair, vice versa, as long as they are the closest to each other and follow the order of 'O' before 'I' and other aforementioned conditions

Comment: @ansey I think this was incorrectly closed. This is more complicated than a simple `drop_duplicates()` as it also requires row-wise comparisons.
`s1 = df.duplicated(subset=['ITEM_ID', 'GROUP'], keep=False)`
`s2 = df.groupby(['ITEM_ID', 'GROUP'])['TYPE'].transform('first') == 'O'`
`s3 = df.groupby(['ITEM_ID', 'GROUP'])['TYPE'].transform('min') == 'I'`
# s1, s2, s3
`df[~(s1 & s2 & s3)]`

Comment: @ansev ^^^ spelled your name incorrectly. See comment above.

Comment: reopened @David Erickson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shift` with `filter`

```
out = df.groupby(['ITEM_ID','GROUP']).filter(lambda x : ~(x['TYPE'].eq('I') & x['TYPE'].shift().eq('O')).any())
Out[7]: 
         id        Date ITEM_ID TYPE GROUP
0  13710750  2019-07-01  SLM607    O     X
1  13710760  2019-07-01  SLM607    O     M
3  13710780  2019-09-03  SLM607    O     N
4  13667449  2019-08-02  887643    O     I
5  13667450  2019-08-02  792184    O     I
7  13667452  2019-08-02  794580    O     I
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. May I ask if `shift()` here only considers the one previous row? Or does it look at all previous rows, as the pairs may not always be adjacent rows.

Comment: @nilsinelabore only consider one previous row

Comment: Do you know if there is any function that considers all previous rows? I've tried searching but couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: Could you please explain what the purpose of  `.any()` in your code? Thank you.

Comment: @nilsinelabore any here is to check if any instance happen return the true , then we will return the whole group

Comment: What I noticed is that an excessive number of rows have been removed and I'm not sure why. It's almost correct, just that the numbers do not quite add up.